# How to specify gamma distribution using shape and rate in Python?

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

With [Scipy gamma distribution](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html), one can only specify shape, loc, and scale. How do I create a gamma variable with shape and rate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inverse scale (`1/scale`) is rate parameter.

So if you have `shape` and `rate` you can create gamma rv with this code

```
>>> from scipy.stats import gamma
>>> rv = gamma(shape, scale = 1.0/rate)
```

Read more about different parametrizations of Gamma distribution on Wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution

Comment: what about loc?

Answer (score 1):

Accodring to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution), rate is 1/scale, so you could use the `scipy` distribution directly or wrap it with something like

```
def my_gamma(x,q,a,loc,freq,size,moments):
    return scipy.stats.gamma(x, q, a,loc, 1.0/freq, size, moments)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with the scale parameter, **rate=1/scale**

in R :

***pgamma(1/2, 2, rate=5)*** and ***pgamma(1/2, 2, scale=0.2)*** are identical

Comment: The question is tagged with `python` and `scipy`, so you should probably mention that `pgamma` is an R function.